# CPLEX warm start with altered objective function coefficient

Tags: optimization, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I am optimizing a MILP model in CPLEX (Python interface) that takes a long time to solve. Sometimes I need to do concurrent runs if my timelimit runs out. In order to continue optimizing with a solution from a previous, unfinished, run I usually provide the .sol file as a warm start.

Now I have a change in the objective function coefficients. The model's constraints and variables stay the same. Is it possible to provide a solution from the 'old', already optimized model to the model with the revised coefficients? Will CPLEX find the optimal solution of the new model faster than just starting fresh, regardless if it is is in the same 'range' as the old solution? And can I provide the .sol file for this as usual or should I use an .mst file?

On a related note, I am finding that when I use a previous solution as a warm start, CPLEX does use the best integer value found previously but often starts with a higher best bound. So the gap initially is higher than what previously has already been reached. Is there a method to overcome this, possibly speeding up the run?

Comment: It is normal that the best possible bound is not as good as before. You may want to use the MIP emphasis or cuts option to move that bound quicker.

Answer (score 0):

you can warmstart with a .sol file but also with APIS

[warm start through API](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoowarmstartapi.py) in https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

warmstart=mdl.new_solution()
warmstart.add_var_value(nbbus40,8)
warmstart.add_var_value(nbbus30,0)
mdl.add_mip_start(warmstart)


sol=mdl.solve(log_output=True)

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Sometimes warmstart helps, some times it does not. Fixed start helps too sometimes.(The search space is smaller so the search can be faster)

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using ".sol" file as mip start, but there is a dedicated format for mip starts: MST format in ".mst" files. If you are using DOcplex, from a solution produced by `Model.solve()`, you can export a mst file using `export_as_mst`, which takes a `WriteLevel` argument.
This enumerated value controls what is written in the MST file: by default, only discrete values are used in the mip start, which avoids precision issues.

This is one of the reasons you should prefer MST format for mip starts.

Comment: I tried the .mst instead of .sol format. Other than improved accuracy, is it supposed to offer any performance improvements? I just ran a problem up to a 12.5% gap. When I restarted the problem with the .mst file, the gap started back at 22%. As mentioned, the best integer remains the same as from the previous instance but the best bound does not. Seems like a waste of processing time?

Comment: A warm start contains a solution, it is not a serialization of the MIP search. It can happen that the best bound, as recomputed by a new solve, is not as good as it was at the end of the previous solve. The interest of MST files  is to give control on what is actually restored (by default it is discrete variables), and avoid numerical issues associated with restoring continuous variables.